# WP Rest API register endpoint

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, oauth-2.0

I tried to register a custom end point with WP Rest API and i implement the function like this:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'myplugin_register_routes');

/**
* Register the /wp-json/myplugin/v1/foo route
*/
function myplugin_register_routes() {
register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', 'foo', array(
    'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
    'callback' => 'myplugin_serve_route',
) );
}


/**
* Generate results for the /wp-json/myplugin/v1/foo route.
*
* @param WP_REST_Request $request Full details about the request.
*
* @return WP_REST_Response|WP_Error The response for the request.
*/
function myplugin_serve_route( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
// Do something with the $request

// Return either a WP_REST_Response or WP_Error object
return $response;
}
```

But i receive an error like this:

[{"code":"json_no_route","message":"No route provides a mapping between the URL and mode \ u00e0 request"}]

How can i do to create a secure end point for my oauth configuration and WP REST API?